Run-time complexity of solving a system of integer linear equations
Given an integer $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ and an integer $n$-by-$1$ vector $b$, what is the run-time complexity of finding an integer solution $x$ to the system $A x = b$?
In general, integer linear programming (ILP) is NP-hard. But a general ILP also has inequalities, and here there are only equations.
One reason I think it can be done in polynomial time is the following. Using the Bareiss algorithm (a variant of Gaussian elimination), one can find in polynomial time a rational solution, where the representation length of the coefficients is polynomial in $n$. By multiplying in the common denominator, one can find an integer solution in polynomial time. Is this algorithm correct?

You can solve this in polynomial time by computing the Hermite normal form of $A$. This is the integer analogue of Gaussian elimination.

With an nxn matrix and an n by n vector, there is usually exactly one solution. So you find it and just check if it is all integers.
Now if the equations are not independent then you have none or ininitely many solutions. Say
3x + 4y = 23
6x + 8y = c for some c

Clearly if c ≠ 46 then you have no solution. If c = 46 then you have an infinite number of rational solutions y = (23 - 3x) / 4. If the numbers 3 and 4 had a common divisor > 1, then you would divide by that and find you have no solutions or ininitely many. Y = (23 - 2x) / 4 = (11.5 - x) / 2, no solution. Y = (22 - 2x) / 4 = (11 - x) / 2, all odd x give a solution.
In my original problem, the first solution is X = 3, y = 5, and then you can increase x y 4K and decrease h by 3k, as often as you like.

So the problem is polynomial? What if $b=0$ and the goal is to find a non-zero solution (if one exists)?
